# What does predict (Keras) return?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I mean, I know what it returns, but what I really dont´t know is like the following example. It gives me this output: `[0.238  0.762]` in a model which has only binary outputs `[0, 1]`.
So I know that it is the probabilities of each class to the input given, but what value corresponds to each class? `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predict returns the Neural Network outputs at the last layer. This is not necessarily the probabilities, but simply depends on what you used in your neural network architecture. The simple answer is that you can run

```
model.predict(x) > 0.5
```

That should work in most cases. The NN will optimize to approach the best solution, but all of the values within are continuous so unless you problem is very easily separable you will rarely get an output that is fully binary.

To answer your question, [0.238  0.762] unless trained strangely likely means [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

For binary classification, the first column is the probability of class 0 and second is of class 1. You can check that in keras code base L257-L260 ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1cf5218edb23e575a827ca4d849f1d52d21b4bb0/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L257-L260)) from `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier`:

```
# check if binary classification
if probs.shape[1] == 1:
    # first column is probability of class 0 and second is of class 1
    probs = np.hstack([1 - probs, probs])
```